# Angular - angular material format - "dd" and "yyyy" in lower case does not display the correct format

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my app.module.ts I have changed the format of my app to be-

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: 'LL',
    },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
        monthYearLabel: 'YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY',
    },
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
        {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

According to what I understand "dd" stands for "day of the month", while "DD" is "day of the year" and "yyyy" specifies the calendar year whereas "YYYY" specifies the year (of “Week of Year”).

But in the date pickers I get this date-"yyyy-03-Tu", only when I change the format to "YYYY-MM-DD" I get the correct date.. any idea why is works like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the MomentDateAdapter which uses [Momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) and it's format specifications.

Momentjs uses:

- `YYYY` for 4-digit years -`yyyy` is not valid and is interpreted as literal text,
- `DD` for 2-digit day of month,
- `dd` for 2-digit day of week.

Check out [MomentJS formatting](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Comment: Thanks! is there other alternative? I saw that material prefer the MomentDateAdapter

Comment: Check out the documentation on [Customizing the parse and display formats](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats)